# My IR5 parent's sponsor visa was refused, section 221(g. What should I do next?

Tags: ir5

My IR5 parent's sponsor visa was refused, saying "additional processing is required."

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, the visa is currently in [Administrative Processing](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/administrative-processing-information.html) and you must wait for it to be adjudicated.

The refusal state is quite misleading, but it is not a decision to refuse your visa.